# Include type information when dereferencing?

Tags: typescript, destructuring, function-parameter

When dereferencing an argument within a function call like this:

```
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) =>
```

Is there a way to include typing information?

For example in this case the dereferenced `data` object is a `ParseResult`.  Can we include that somehow within the dereferencing syntax?

The end goal is to get autocomplete working within the function.

I could do something like:

```
const result:ParseResult = data
```

But I'm curious as to whether there is a shorter more sugared approach?

Comment: You can use `typeof` to get what type it is.

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to get to something like {data:ParseResult} such that autocomplete works with data inside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately one cannot put types directly on the individual identifiers in the destructuring pattern, one can only type the whole parameter:

```
worker.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: ParseResult }) =>
```

Comment: It's nice to know that the Gods of Typescript are out there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want (not sure to understand your question)

```
interface ParseResult{
    data: string;
}

const testder = ({ data }: ParseResult) =>{
    console.log(data);
}


const para:ParseResult= {
    data:"test"
}

testder(para)
```